# How to populate columns based on conditions without creating multiple rows per unique client in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that shows if a client has had a specific event every week within a 12 week period from when they entered a program. I only want one row to generate for each client which shows if they've had a specified event during week 1, week 2, all the way to week 12 and populate the date of the event in the given columns. The issue is instead of populating within the created columns, a new row will generate for the same client for each date of the specified event.

What I get:

| Client | Week 1 | Week 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | date 1 |  |
| 1 |  | date 2 |

Vs what I want:

| Client | Week 1 | Week 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | date 1 | date 2 |
| 2 | date 1 | date 2 |

So far I have primarily tried using a combination of common table expressions (CTE) and CASE statements to try and solve this. My thought process was to create a CTE that stores the events and dates of events for each client, then use a CASE statement in my main query to see if a client has a matching record in the CTE and populate the date of the event in a new column. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
With cssrs as (
Select people_id, event_name, event_date
from event_table
Where event_name in ('event_one', 'event_two', 'event_three')
)

Select cc.agency_id_number, cc.full_name, cc.program_name, cc.program_start_date,

CASE
    WHEN cc.people_id in (cssrs.people_id) and cssrs.actual_date between cc.program_start_date and   DATEADD(d, 7, cc.program_start_date) THEN cssrs.actual_date
END AS 'CSSRS Service Week 1'

CASE
    WHEN cc.people_id in (cssrs.people_id) and cssrs.actual_date between DATEADD(d, 7, cc.program_start_date) and   DATEADD(d, 14, cc.program_start_date) THEN cssrs.actual_date
END AS 'CSSRS Service Week 2'

From people_table cc

Left Join cssrs
On cc.people_id = cssrs.people_id and cssrs.actual_date >= cc.program_start_date
```

Comment: What if there's more than one "event one" in a given week?  What date do you want to use?

Comment: From what I've gathered there should only ever be one of these events during a given week. If there are multiple I would have to see how my agency would want to handle that since that would mean someone else made an error. That is a good thing for me to keep in mind though thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to summarize, which means using the `GROUP BY` operator.

There are a bunch of ways to approach this, but here's a very conceptually simple one:

(Please note: I did this from memory and didn't check it for syntax.)

```
With cssrs as (
Select people_id, event_name, event_date
from   event_table
Where  event_name in ('event_one', 'event_two', 'event_three')
)
, named_weeks AS (

Select cc.agency_id_number, 
       cc.full_name, 
       cc.program_name, 
       cc.program_start_date,

    CASE
    WHEN cc.people_id in (cssrs.people_id) 
     and cssrs.actual_date between cc.program_start_date and DATEADD(d, 7, cc.program_start_date) 
    THEN cssrs.actual_date
    END AS  [CSSRS Service Week 1]

    CASE
    WHEN cc.people_id in (cssrs.people_id) 
     and cssrs.actual_date between DATEADD(d, 7, cc.program_start_date) and   DATEADD(d, 14, cc.program_start_date) 
    THEN cssrs.actual_date
    END AS [CSSRS Service Week 2]

From people_table cc
    Left Join cssrs
        On   cc.people_id = cssrs.people_id 
         and cssrs.actual_date >= cc.program_start_date
)

SELECT agency_id_number, 
       cc.full_name, 
       cc.program_name, 
       cc.program_start_date,
       MIN(nw.[CSSRS Service Week 1]) as [CSSRS Service Week 1],  -- Could be MAX instead
       MIN(nw.[CSSRS Service Week 2]) as [CSSRS Service Week 2]

FROM   named_weeks nw
GROUP BY agency_id_number
    ,    full_name
    ,    program_name
    ,    program_start_date
ORDER BY agency_id_number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can bring only one register for each people you can use the distinct on the people_id.

like this:

```
Select distinct(people_id)
```